# Basic issue with C double pointers (matrices)

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, double-pointer

I am relatively new to programming in general, and I'm trying to write some code to work with square matrices. Unfortunately, I'm stuck very early in the development, as the code

```
typedef struct Matrix_t{
    float** content;
    size_t size;
} Matrix_t;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Matrix_t* matr;

    initMatrix(matr,s);
    /*
    ...
    ...
    ...
    */
    return 0;
}

void initMatrix(Matrix_t* m, size_t s) {
    int i;

    m = (Matrix_t*) malloc(sizeof(Matrix_t));
    m->content = (float**) malloc(s*sizeof(float*));
    for(i=0;i<s;i++){
        m->content[i] = (float*) malloc(s*sizeof(float));
    }

    m->size = s;
}
```

would SIGSEGV immediately after initMatrix() is done.
Using the debugger, I found out that basically all matrix info is lost after initMatrix() is closed. Why is it? And how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `m = ...` if you think this will affect the pointer passed in from `main()`, you may want to rethink that. Further, I see no reason to dynamically allocate `Matrix_t` in the first place. Its relevant *content* is already dynamic-managed. What are you gaining but a few more bytes on the heap?

Comment: Variable `m` is a local variable in function `initMatrix`. Anything you set it to is irrelevant outside the function. In essence, the allocated memory is "lost" (a.k.a. *memory leak*) once this function completes.

Comment: @barakmanos `m` is local but it's actually the `matr` variable's address. You pass a Matrix pointer to the function, function pointer points to allocated memory, after return of `initMatrix`, `m` should still have the allocated memory address. Am I wrong? It's weird that code doesn't work. What do you think?

Comment: Ah! Address of pointer should be passed. I got it thanks to WhozCraig

Comment: I suggest avoiding the phrase "double pointer". It could refer to a pointer to a pointer, as it does here, but it also refers to the type `double*`. Click on the "double-pointer" tag, which takes you to the tag wiki that discusses this issue.

Comment: @MustafaChelik: Yes, you are wrong. OP is passing **the value** of `matr`, not the address (and the function doesn't take a `Matrix_t**` argument anyway, so if OP passed the address of that variable, then the code wouldn't even compile).

Comment: a few suggestions:  1) eliminate the typedef and simply define a struct type. (note: references to that type will then need to be prefixed with 'struct'  2) add the missing prototype for the 'initMatrix' function  3) always check the returned value from a call to malloc() to assure the operation was successful.  4) change this line: 'initMatrix(matr,s);' (and associated code) to: 'initMatrix(&matr,s);' so can change the actual contents of the matr variable.  5) for several reasons, do not cast the returned value from a call to malloc  6) always set pointers to an initial value when defined

Comment: Consider using a contiguous memory bloc for the matrix , instead of a jagged array.

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying only a local automatic variable `m` in your function. C is a pass-by-value language. If you want to pass by address, then an address is what you have to pass, declaring the formal parameter as a pointer-to-type, **even when that type is already a pointer and what you're modifying is the *the pointer itself***.

When you're passing something as an in/out or out parameter, If you find yourself doing this:

```
void foo(Type *p)
{
    p = malloc(...)
}
```

you're **not** modifying the data pointed to *by `p`*, you're modifying `p` itself, and the caller will be unaware of the change. The address stored in `p` upon entrance is lost. Where as this:

```
void foo(Type *p)
{
    *p = ....
}
```

is modifying what `p` *points to*. That said, if `Type` is already a pointer-type, and what you want to modify it the *pointer* itself, you must do this:

```
void foo(Type **pp) // declare a pointer-to-pointer-to-type
{
    *pp = malloc(....) // dereference to store the address returned from malloc
                       // in the pointer pointed to by pp
}
```

---

Therefore, the most immediate fix is to declare the formal parameter as a pointer-to-pointer-to-type, passing the address of `matr` from `main()`

```
void initMatrix(Matrix_t **pp, size_t s) 
{
    int i;

    Matrix_t *m = malloc(sizeof(Matrix_t));
    m->content = malloc(s*sizeof(float*));
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        m->content[i] = malloc(s*sizeof(float));
    m->size = s;
    *pp = m; // note: saving pointer to the output target
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Matrix_t* matr = NULL;

    initMatrix(&matr,s); // note: passing address of pointer

    /*
    ...
    ...
    ...
    */
    return 0;
}
```

I left out the error checking (or I should say, I didn't *add* any, as there was none there to begin with) and removed the unneeded casts from `malloc`, which you can read more about [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

There are about a half-dozen ways to do this, but this is the most direct to what code you already have. I would advise either returning the allocation from the function itself as the ret-val, or not even dynamic-allocating the structure itself as there is no need to do so. Both of which I leave for you to think about.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Make matr=NULL in main function and so, try:

```
main(){

   Matrix_t *matr=NULL;
   /*Declare and initialize "s" variable.... */

   initMatrix(&matr,s);  /* See below...  */
   /*
     .....
   */
}
```

Use a pointer to pointer in Matrix_t *m in function initMatrix

```
void initMatrix(Matrix_t **m, size_t s) 
{    
     Matrix_t *aux=(Matrix_t*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix_t));

     /*check if matrix already allocated */  
     if(*m != NULL) 
     {    
         /*Make a free matrix function to free the matrix before use*/          
         free_my_matrix(m); 
         *m=NULL;
     }

     /***
        Work with aux....
        aux->content=...malloc....
     ***/

     /* make your base pointer be aux */           
     *m=aux; 
}
```